# Trying to figure out Big 0 notations for my program

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, notation

Hello I am trying to figure out the big 0 notation for my code but having trouble with it. I am new to algorithms and don't know what processes increase 0(n) to 0(n<sup>2</sup>) for example.

```
package gmit;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class TestRunner {
    // Creating Hashmap
    private static HashMap<String, String> stringmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Creating String Array lists
    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    private static ArrayList<String> lol = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Declaring int variables
    private static int encryptioncounter=0,decryptioncounter=0,lastindexcounter=0,
            mylistindexcounter=0,resortcounter=0;
    // Declaring String variables
    private static String password,value;
    private static String result,text;


    // ----------------------------------------------- Main start --------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        System.out.println("Pleaseinput your passphrase");
        // Gets user Input
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        password = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please input the file name you want to encrypt.(WarAndPeace-LeoTolstoy.txt)");
        // Gets user Input
        Scanner tin = new Scanner(System.in);
         text = tin.nextLine();

        //Starts Timer
         long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        // Method to populate HashMap
         putstuffinstrinmap();

        // Starts for loop
        // Creates Array list in number of the amount of characters of the password
        // Adds created arraylists to Arraylist<List> mylist.

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            List<String> firstCharandMore= new ArrayList<>();
            char c = password.charAt(i);
            firstCharandMore.add(String.valueOf(c));
            String resortcountertostring= String.valueOf(resortcounter);
                mylist.add((ArrayList<String>) firstCharandMore);
                // Adds index for resort to arraylists
                mylist.get(i).add(resortcountertostring);
                //mylist.add((ArrayList<String>) resortcountertostring);
                resortcounter++;
            }

        // Reads in File in UTF-8 format
        // gets back a character
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(text),
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            int c;
            while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
              char string = (char) c;

              // Converts Character to upper case String
              // Passes the string into encryption method
              encrypt(Character.toString(string).toUpperCase());
              // Adds one to counter
              decryptioncounter++;

            }
            //long endTime2   = System.nanoTime();
            //long totalTime2 = endTime2 - startTime;
            //double seconds2 = (double)totalTime2 / 1000000000.0;
            //System.out.println(seconds2+" Encryption");
            // Creates new Arraylist listToSort (Copy of mylist)
            // Sorts Array lists in alphabetic order by first character from each list
            sortarraylists();

            writetofileencrypted();
            // Resorts arraylists using the index
            resortarraylist();

            // Calls decryption method
            decrypt();
            // Calls write to file method
            writetofilefin();
            // Ends Timer
            long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            // Prints Time
            double seconds = (double)totalTime / 1000000000.0;
            System.out.println(seconds+" Total time");       
    }
    // ------------------------------------ End Main -----------------------------------------

    // Writes encrypted message to file.
    private static void writetofileencrypted() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter writer2 = new PrintWriter("encrypted.txt", "UTF-8");
        StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (ArrayList<String> value : mylist) {
            builder2.append(value);
        }
        String s = builder2.toString();
        //String s = lol.toString();
        writer2.println(s);
        writer2.close();
    }

    // -------------------------------------resorting-----------------------------------------
    private static void resortarraylist() {
        // Resorts lists using index 1 (The numbers assigned to that index))
        mylist.sort((l1, l2) -> l1.get(1).compareTo(l2.get(1)));
    }
    // ------------------------------------End resorting --------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------ Sorting ------------------------------------------
    private static void sortarraylists() {
        // Sorting lists in alphabetical order by index 0
        mylist.sort((l1, l2) -> l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0)));
    }
    // ------------------------------------End sorting ---------------------------------------

    // ------------------------------------write to file --------------------------------------
    private static void writetofilefin() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // Prints to array list lol to file
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("finished.txt", "UTF-8");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String value : lol) {
            builder.append(value);
        }
        String s = builder.toString();
        //String s = lol.toString();
        writer.println(s);
        writer.close();

    }


    // -------------------------------- Encryption Start -------------------------------------
    private static void encrypt(String string) {

        // Gets coherent value from map 
        value= stringmap.get(string);
        // adds value to mylist at index encryptioncounter 
        mylist.get(encryptioncounter).add(value);
        // Adds one to counter
        encryptioncounter++;
        // Resets encryptioncounter 
        if(encryptioncounter>=password.length()){
            encryptioncounter=0;
            // Adds one to lastindexcounter
            lastindexcounter++;
        }       
    }
    // --------------------------------- Encryption End ---------------------------------------

    // --------------------------------- Decryption Start -------------------------------------
    private static void decrypt() {

        int thiscounter=0;
        // runs until decryptioncounter is = to thiscounter or 
        // mylistindexcounter is = to lastindexcounter
        while(decryptioncounter   != thiscounter  ){
            for(int i=0;i <password.length() ;i++){
                // gets value from Arraylist 
                String ba = mylist.get(i).get(mylistindexcounter);//0(1)
                // gets coherent value from map 
                result= stringmap.get(ba);// 0(n)
                // adds value to arraylist lol
                lol.add(result);
                thiscounter++;
                if(mylistindexcounter >=lastindexcounter){
                    decryptioncounter =thiscounter;
                }
            }
            mylistindexcounter++;
        }       
    }
    // ---------------------------------- Decryption End ---------------------------------------

    // --------------------------------- Map population start ---------------------------------
    // 0(1)
    public static void putstuffinstrinmap(){
        stringmap.put("AA", "P");//AA - P
        stringmap.put("AD", "H");//AD - H
        stringmap.put("AF", "0");//
        stringmap.put("AG", "Q");//
        stringmap.put("AV", "G");//
        stringmap.put("AX", "6");//
        stringmap.put("DA", "4");//
        stringmap.put("DD", "M");//
        stringmap.put("DF", "E");//
        stringmap.put("DG", "A");//
        stringmap.put("DV", "1");//
        stringmap.put("DX", "Y");//
        stringmap.put("FA", "L");//
        stringmap.put("FD", "2");//
        stringmap.put("FF", "N");//
        stringmap.put("FG", "O");//
        stringmap.put("FV", "F");//
        stringmap.put("FX", "D");//
        stringmap.put("GA", "X");//
        stringmap.put("GD", "K");//
        stringmap.put("GF", "R");//
        stringmap.put("GG", "3");//
        stringmap.put("GV", "C");//
        stringmap.put("GX", "V");//
        stringmap.put("VA", "S");//
        stringmap.put("VD", "5");//
        stringmap.put("VF", "Z");//
        stringmap.put("VG", "W");//
        stringmap.put("VV", "7");//
        stringmap.put("VX", "B");//
        stringmap.put("XA", "J");//
        stringmap.put("XD", "9");//
        stringmap.put("XF", "U");//
        stringmap.put("XG", "T");//
        stringmap.put("XV", "I");//
        stringmap.put("XX", "8");//     
        stringmap.put("P", "AA");//
        stringmap.put("H", "AD");//
        stringmap.put("0", "AF");//
        stringmap.put("Q", "AG");//
        stringmap.put("G", "AV");//
        stringmap.put("6", "AX");//
        stringmap.put("4", "DA");//
        stringmap.put("M", "DD");//
        stringmap.put("E", "DF");//
        stringmap.put("A", "DG");//
        stringmap.put("1", "DV");//
        stringmap.put("Y", "DX");//
        stringmap.put("L", "FA");//
        stringmap.put("2", "FD");//
        stringmap.put("N", "FF");//
        stringmap.put("O", "FG");//
        stringmap.put("F", "FV");//
        stringmap.put("D", "FX");//
        stringmap.put("X", "GA");//
        stringmap.put("K", "GD");//
        stringmap.put("R", "GF");//
        stringmap.put("3", "GG");//
        stringmap.put("C", "GV");//
        stringmap.put("V", "GX");//
        stringmap.put("S", "VA");//
        stringmap.put("5", "VD");//
        stringmap.put("Z", "VF");//
        stringmap.put("W", "VG");//
        stringmap.put("7", "VV");//
        stringmap.put("B", "VX");//
        stringmap.put("J", "XA");//
        stringmap.put("9", "XD");//
        stringmap.put("U", "XF");//
        stringmap.put("T", "XG");//
        stringmap.put("I", "XV");//
        stringmap.put("8", "XX");// 
        stringmap.put("AH", ".");//
        stringmap.put("DH", "!");//
        stringmap.put("FH", "?");//
        stringmap.put("GH", " ");//
        stringmap.put("VH", "'");//
        stringmap.put("XH", ",");//
        stringmap.put(".", "AH");//
        stringmap.put("!", "DH");//
        stringmap.put("?", "FH");//
        stringmap.put(" ", "GH");//
        stringmap.put("'", "VH");//
        stringmap.put(",", "XH");//     
        stringmap.put("AP", "]");//
        stringmap.put("DP", "[");//
        stringmap.put("FP", "~");//
        stringmap.put("GP", "&");//
        stringmap.put("VP", ":");//
        stringmap.put("XP", ";");//
        stringmap.put("AP", "-");//"
        stringmap.put("DP", "");//
        stringmap.put("FP", "*");//
        stringmap.put("GP", "^");//
        stringmap.put("VP", "\"");//
        stringmap.put(null, " ");//
    }
    // --------------------------------- Map population End -----------------------------------

}
```

Any help explaining it using my code or guiding me to some reading material would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need a `Total time` to find a Big O. Big O notation is use to find count of elementary operations in algorithm. Like write `n` elements of array is O(n) because you need write every element. For matrix of size `n*n` it's O(n^2). I think, so i your algorithm Big O is O(n*m+k). Where `n` is count of steps `while(decryption counter!= thecounter)` loop, `m` is length of password and k is other operations, loops. Usually `k` don't add to Big O because is much smaller than n*m, but in your case I'm not sure about it.